# Remove all duplicates by multiple variables with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to remove all duplicate values based on multiple variable using `dplyr`. Here's how I do it without `dplyr`:

```
dat = data.frame(id=c(1,1,2),date=c(1,1,1))
dat = dat[!(duplicated(dat[c('id','date')]) | duplicated(dat[c('id','date')],fromLast=TRUE)),]
```

It should only return id number 2.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a `group_by/filter` operation in `tidyverse`.  Grouped by the columns of interest (here used `group_by_all` as all the columns in the dataset are grouped.  Instead can also make use of `group_by_at` if a selected number of columns are needed)

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
   group_by_all() %>%
   filter(n()==1)
```

---

Or simply `group_by`

```
dat %>% 
   group_by(id, date) %>%
   filter(n() == 1)
```

---

If the OP intended to use the `duplicated` function

```
dat %>%
  filter_at(vars(id, date),
        any_vars(!(duplicated(.)|duplicated(., fromLast = TRUE))))
# id date
#1  2    1
```

Comment: or `dat %>% 
  count(id, date) %>% 
  filter(n < 2)`

Comment: @Jimbou. One issue with `count` would be that it summarise and remove the other columns

Comment: you are right. `add_count(id, date)` would be the better option. But my feelings lead me to `dat %>% 
  distinct_all()`